# I can't figure out how to use $group , $sum and $avg in the same mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i am learning node js with mongodb when i face a problem while working in a little project, i have a collection of orders and i want to calculate some statistics for it like total price which is the sum of all order prices ( sum of orderPrice ) , the avg of the total price which is the sum of order prices divided on number of orders , the sum of responseTime and the avg of response time , this is the array :

```
[
 {  
    _id:"eyxwapfhiezfe664ec",
    orderPrice : 20,
    responseTime : 10, 
    createdAt :  2021-01-15T17:16:25.844Z
     
 }
 {
   _id:"eyxwlcfeojrfeoc",
    orderPrice : 50,
    responseTime : 10, 
    createdAt :  2021-01-15T17:16:25.844Z
     
 }
 {
   _id:"eyxwapfhiseflflpsssc",
    orderPrice : 20,
    responseTime : 7, 
    createdAt :  2021-01-15T17:16:25.844Z
     
 }
 {  
   _id:"eyxwapfhdfghkdfps",
    orderPrice : 12,
    responseTime : 5, 
    createdAt :  2021-01-16T17:16:25.844Z
     
 }
 {  
   _id:"eyxwapfhiezzefllc",
    orderPrice : 30,
    responseTime : 10, 
    createdAt :  2021-01-16T17:16:25.844Z
     
 }

]
```

the more difficult thing for me is the result shoud be an array of one day in each case so i have to do the operations i mentioned for every day that's why i have to group the documents in the array by day ,
the outpout should look like this

```
   [
   {
     day:2021-01-15 , 
     totalPrice: 90 , 
     avgPrice:30 , 
     totalTime: 27 , 
     avgTime: 9
   }
   {
     day:2021-01-16 , 
     totalPrice: 42 , 
     avgPrice:21 , 
     totalTime: 15 , 
     avgTime: 7.5
   }
   { 
     total: {
               totalPrice: 132 , 
               avgPrice:26,4 , 
               totalTime: 42 , 
               avgTime: 8.5
             }
   }
   ]
```

i don't know if this is possible using only mongodb aggregate methods , if not how can i do it using the minimum javascript code , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use facet to achieve this, with two grouping stages inside it.
The first one will aggregate by null to compute the metrics with your whole dataset, and the second one will group by day.
The tricky thing is go get the day from your date string.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "metricsTotal": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            sumOrderPrice: {
              $sum: "$orderPrice"
            },
            avgOrderPrice: {
              $avg: "$orderPrice"
            },
            sumResponseTime: {
              $sum: "$responseTime"
            },
            avgResponseTime: {
              $avg: "$responseTime"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "metricsByDay": [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              $dateFromParts: {
                "year": {
                  "$year": {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      "dateString": "$createdAt",
                      
                    }
                  }
                },
                "month": {
                  "$month": {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      "dateString": "$createdAt",
                      
                    }
                  }
                },
                "day": {
                  "$dayOfMonth": {
                    $dateFromString: {
                      "dateString": "$createdAt",
                      
                    }
                  },
                  
                }
              }
            },
            sumOrderPrice: {
              $sum: "$orderPrice"
            },
            avgOrderPrice: {
              $avg: "$orderPrice"
            },
            sumResponseTime: {
              $sum: "$responseTime"
            },
            avgResponseTime: {
              $avg: "$responseTime"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q7xSt7F-iVI)

Comment: thank you sir your answer looks very close but i tried it but is giving me an empty arrays , what if my two dates are not string ? how can i change the query you gave me ?

Comment: if your createdAt field is ISOdate, you have to remove the $dateFromString part and simply use the field, ex : "year": {   "$year": "$createdAt" }
Here's the updated playground :  https://mongoplayground.net/p/x-yBbDrbTSa

Comment: Thank you , your answer helped me